# How to fetch information from rest in php?

Tags: php, rest

How to fetch information from rest in `php`?

I have an `url` and I wanna extract information from web service by `php`.

Comment: always show minimal of your trying code before ask

Answer (score 1):

**Example of calling GET request**

```
//next example will recieve all messages for specific conversation
$service_url = 'http://example.com/api/conversations/[CONV_CODE]/messages&apikey=[API_KEY]';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded->response);
```

Reference : [How to make REST calls in PHP](http://support.qualityunit.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `curl` if is enable on your host.